# How can I print user inputted text with LC3?

Tags: printing, lc3

So I'm trying to take a user inputted string and print it out with the preceding text "The text you have typed is:" but I have no idea how to get the first string saved into a register and accessible for the next string. 
Secondly, how can I increase the character limit so that I can later analyze how many characters there are in the user's string? At the moment, anything over 16 gives me an unsigned number error.

Any ideas? Cheers.

My current code:

```
Lea r0, EnterText
puts

lea r4 TextSave

LOOP
getc

add r1, r0, -10
brz OUTSIDE 

add r2, r2, 1

str r0, r4, 0 
add r4, r4, 1

out
brnzp LOOP

OUTSIDE

Lea r0, EnterText
Add r0, r0, r0
puts

Lea r0, UserEnter
Add r0, r0, r0 
puts

lea r0, UserEnter
puts

lea r0, TextSave
puts

Lea r0, CharacterText
puts 

ld r0, CharZero
add r0, r0, r2
out

Halt
EnterText .stringz "Please enter a text: "
UserEnter .stringz "\nThe text you have typed is: "
TextSave .blkw 99
CharacterText .stringz "\nThe amount of characters you have entered including spaces:"
CharZero .fill #99

.end
```

Comment: Could you provide the code directly in your post, rather than via link?  Links can change/go stale, and it would help future readers if your code was directly available in your post.

Comment: Ah yep, sorry about that. Just editted the post and added the code in text.